# Moxa embedded programming: weird error

Tags: c++, embedded, embedded-linux, microcontroller

I am currently working on a project where we are using a Moxa EM-1220-LX running linux, programming it using C++. During the development I have come across a bizzare error.

I have the following code:

```
std::string vector_to_string(std::vector<int> vec) {
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        ss << vec[i] << ".";
    }
    return ss.str();
}

void print_string(std::string text) {
    std::cout << text << "\n";
}

std::vector<int> local_vector;
local_vector.push_back(123);
local_vector.push_back(456);
local_vector.push_back(789);

//Case 1: Prints 456.789.
print_string(vector_to_string(local_vector));

//Case 2: Prints 123.456.789.
std::string temp = vector_to_string(local_vector);
print_string(temp);
```

Anyone have any idea why the first entry in the vector gets removed in Case 1, but works fine in Case 2?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue by compiling the code from the question. Perphaps you have a bug somewhere else in the code which causes heap/stack corruption.

---

Old answer: you seem to have a bug here:

```
for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
    ss << vec << ".";
}
```

Shouldn't the middle line read `ss << vec[i] << ".";`? This may well explain why your vector is not printed properly.

Comment: Ah, thanks. But that was just an error in the post. Edited it now :)